# Does youtube-dl library support download stories from instagram?

Tags: python, shell, command-line, instagram, youtube-dl

I Use library called YouTube-dl, which can download from many sites.

it's support cookies files. I made the following code:

```
youtube-dl -j —-cookies /path/to/cookies.txt URLgoesHere
```

What I want is how to download stories from Instagram using this library? On the command line.

Answer (score 18):

**Update:** For Instagram stories of **video** slideshows, use [yt-dlp](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp) (requires v2022.1.21):

```sh
pip install 'yt-dlp>=2022.1.21'
```

Just make sure you're logged in via one of the authentication methods:

- `--cookies-from-browser YOUR_BROWSER`
- `--cookies /path/to/cookies.txt`
- `-u YOUR_USERNAME` (interactive)
- `-n` ([config file](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp#authentication-with-netrc-file))

```sh
yt-dlp --cookies-from-browser firefox https://www.instagram.com/stories/highlights/17863022906349328/

# [cookies] Extracting cookies from firefox
# [cookies] Extracted 2051 cookies from firefox
# [instagram:story] 17863022906349328: Downloading JSON metadata
# [instagram:story] 17863022906349328: Downloading JSON metadata
# [instagram:story] 17863022906349328: Downloading user info
# [download] Downloading playlist: Mars AR
# [instagram:story] playlist Mars AR: Collected 7 videos; downloading 7 of them
# [download] Downloading video 1 of 7
# [info] 2515578473642074643_787132: Downloading 1 format(s): 2
# [download] Destination: Story by natgeo [2515578473642074643_787132].mp4
# [download] 100% of 793.91KiB in 00:00
# ⋮
# [download] Finished downloading playlist: Mars AR
```

For Instagram stories of **image** slideshows, use [gallery-dl](https://github.com/mikf/gallery-dl):

```sh
pip install gallery-dl
```

```sh
gallery-dl -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD https://www.instagram.com/stories/highlights/17857710373716419/

# [instagram][info] Logging in as USERNAME
# ./gallery-dl/instagram/weighthefish/2224872001634244851.jpg
# ./gallery-dl/instagram/weighthefish/2224872078683640644.jpg
# ...
# ./gallery-dl/instagram/weighthefish/2224872839329073284.jpg
```

---

Note that [yt-dlp](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp) is a fork of [youtube-dl](https://github.com/yt-dlp/youtube-dl) (I am not affiliated with either):

> [yt-dlp](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp) is a [youtube-dl](https://github.com/yt-dlp/youtube-dl) fork based on the now inactive [youtube-dlc](https://github.com/blackjack4494/yt-dlc). The main focus of this project is adding [new features](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp#new-features) and patches while also keeping up to date with the original project.

[youtube-dl](https://github.com/yt-dlp/youtube-dl) still doesn't support Instagram stories, though it's [tagged as "todo" on their issue tracker](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues/25575).

Comment: give the command to do install stories .

Comment: @DISASTER updated with install/usage commands for `yt-dlp` (just make sure the story really contains videos, not just an image slideshow)

Comment: also updated with [`gallery-dl`](https://github.com/mikf/gallery-dl) commands for stories of image slideshows

Comment: you have my respect.

Answer (score 0):

Just type

`yt-dlp --cookies-from-browser chrome <your link (stories link)>`

make sure your browser is closed,
if you do this while the browser is on, the code may not work.

Comment: Please, [edit] and try for [answer], describe the effect of what you propose and explain why it helps to solve the problem. Please avoid the impression to ask a question instead of answering.  Consider taking the [tour].

Answer (score -2):

It does now, and very gracefully, checked on version: 2021.04.17

`youtube-dl https://www.instagram.com/p/<story_link>/`

Comment: insta stories are `/stories/...` (not `/p/...`) and `/stories/...` links still do not work with youtube-dl

Comment: they are posts :)

Comment: It does not work.


Tried several ways:
youtube-dl https://www.instagram.com/stories/<account_name>/<numeric_id>

youtube-dl https://www.instagram.com/stories/<numeric_id>

youtube-dl https://www.instagram.com/p/<account_name>/<numeric_id>

youtube-dl https://www.instagram.com/p/<numeric_id>

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I got confused with Reels..